# Variation of the zebra puzzle in prolog, and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong

Tags: prolog, zebra-puzzle

I know the *zebra* puzzle is asked often here, but this is a bit different: We were given a variation of the *zebra* puzzle in Prolog to write. I'm super new to this, but I even tried getting help from some people last year who had themselves a different variation, and they weren't sure what was going on with my code.

I'll post the whole thing, I hope it's not overwhelming or bad practice.

```erlang
register_renderer/2

:- use_rendering(table,
         [header(dorm('Major', 'Car', 'Team', 'Music', 'Drink'))]).

csMusic(Music) :-
  dorms(Dorms),
  member(dorm(computerscience,_,_,Music,_),Dorms).

engDrink(Drink) :-
  dorms(Dorms),
  member(dorm(english,_,_,_,Drink),Dorms).

dorms(Dorms) :-
      length(Dorms, 5),

      % 1.  The computer science student lives in the middle of the corridor.
      Dorms = [_,_,(dorm(computerscience,_,_,_,_)),_,_],
      % 2.  The history major is a jazz fan.
      member(dorm(history,_,_,jazz,_),Dorms),
      % 3.  The Yankees fan drives a Toyota.
      member(dorm(_,toyota,yankees,_,_),Dorms),
      % 4.  The accounting major drinks Coke.
      member(dorm(accounting,_,_,_,coke),Dorms),
      % 5.  The engineering major drinks coffee.
      member(dorm(engineering,_,_,_,coffee),Dorms),
      % 6.  The computer science student and history student are neighbors.
      adjacent((dorm(computerscience,_,_,_,_)),(dorm(history,_,_,_,_)),Dorms),
      % 7.  The student at the far end of the hall likes classical music.
      Dorms = [_,_,_,_,(dorm(_,_,_,classical,_))],
      % 8.  The tea drinker drives a Tesla.
      member(dorm(_,_,_,_,_),Dorms),
      % 9.  The classical music fan lives next to the jazz listener.
      adjacent((dorm(_,_,_,classical,_)),(dorm(_,_,_,jazz,_)),Dorms),
      % 10. The English major does not live in either of the first two rooms.
      member(dorm(english,_,_,_,_),Dorms),
      not(Dorms = [dorm(english,_,_,_,_)]),
      not(Dorms = [_,dorm(english,_,_,_,_),_,_,_]),
      % 11. The Royals fan drives a Tesla.
      member(dorm(_,tesla,royals,_,_),Dorms),
      % 12. The Cubs fan listens to jazz.
      member(dorm(_,_,cubs,jazz,_),Dorms),
      % 13. The engineering major follows the Chiefs
      member(dorm(engineering,_,chiefs,_,_),Dorms),
      % 14. The first room is the home of the Broncos fan
      Dorms = [dorms(_,_,broncos,_,_),_,_,_,_],
      % 15. The Coke drinker drives a Nissan.
      member(dorm(_,nissan,_,_,coke),Dorms),
      % 16. The country music fan and the techno fan are neighbors.
      adjacent((dorm(_,_,_,country,_)),(dorm(_,_,_,techno,_)),Dorms),
      % 17. The accounting major lives in the first room.
      Dorms = [dorms(accounting,_,_,_,_),_,_,_,_],
      % 18. The fans of the 2 Kansas City teams (Chiefs and Royals) are neighbors
      adjacent((dorm(_,_,chiefs,_,_)),(dorm(_,_,royals,_,_)),Dorms),
      % 19. The accounting major listens to rock music
      member(dorm(accounting,_,_,rock,_),Dorms),
      % 20. The Yankees fan drinks milk.
      member(dorm(_,_,yankees,_,milk),Dorms),
      % 21. The Chevy driver listens to country music.
      member(dorm(_,chevy,_,country,_),Dorms),
      % 22. The jazz fan drives a Ford.
      member(dorm(_,ford,_,jazz,_),Dorms),
      % 23. Water isnt used.
      member(dorm(_,_,_,_,water),Dorms).

next(A, B, Ls) :- append(_, [A,B|_], Ls).
next(A, B, Ls) :- append(_, [B,A|_], Ls).
adjacent(A,B,List) :- next(A,B,List); next(B,A,List).
```

My database loads just fine, but results in false when I try to run anything. If I run `dorms(Dorms)` to print out all the results, I am returned **`false`**. When I run `csMusic` (trying to find the type of music the CS major listens to) or `engDrink` (trying to find what kind of drink the English major drinks), I am returned **`false`**.

I know quite little of Prolog, but I did my best to follow along on the **swipl** website when going over this problem. Is there perhaps something easy I'm missing that anyone could point out? An inconsistency in naming, perhaps?

Help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your definition of `adjacent/3` has a redundant rule, but that shouldn't affect your answer, just make things run slower. Try these queries:
`forall(adjacent(A,B,[1,2,3]), format('~q~n', [A-B]))` and `forall(next(A,B,[1,2,3]), format('~q~n', [A-B]))`

Comment: "% 23. Water isnt used."
      `member(dorm(_,_,_,_,water),Dorms).` says the opposite.

Comment: after you fix your error/typo in the rule 10 (and 23?), move all the `not`-using goals to the very end, see if it helps.

Comment: @WillNess "Water isn't used" was a poor comment by me - I meant to say that I needed to ensure that a member in the dorms drank water, but it wasn't explicitly stated in my rule set on the assignment, so that was my way of ensuring someone drank water.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In clause 8, I didn't actually mention tea or Tesla.
In clause 10, my first use of not had the incorrect number of items in the array.
In clauses 14 and 17, I misspelled dorm as 'dorms'.

Fixing these, I was able to receive the correct and complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

If `dorms(Dorms)` fails, then certainly `csMusic(Music)` will fail because it requires `dorms(Dorms)` to succeed.

One way to find the problem is to try commenting out some clues and then run the query `dorms(Dorms)`. You'll find that you get multiple solutions. Eventually you'll find one clue that causes failure. Of course, that might not be the bad clue.

Another thing that might be wrong is the use of "not". For example, if you run this query:

```
?- length(Dorms, 5), not(Dorms = [dorm(english,_,_,_,_)]).  % 10.
Dorms = [_9200, _9206, _9212, _9218, _9224].
```

is that result what you expect? You might want to review the "closed world assumption" that Prolog uses for negation and consider an alternative way of writing this clue.

Minor point: there's no need to put parentheses around `dorm(...)`. For example, the first constraint can be written `Dorms = [_,_,dorm(computerscience,_,_,_,_),_,_]`.